# Angular 6 Reactive Form Add Error Class Container Div

Tags: angular

Using an Angular 6 directive or component, what is the simplest error proof solution to adding a has-error class to the container div when the input is invalid etc.

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group has-error"> // add has-error here.
  <label> Email address </label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control m-input" formControlName="email">
  <span class="m-form__help"> Email is required. </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing you use `form` as `formGroup` ie: `<form [formGroup]="form">`

you can check if the email has error by: `form.get('email').invalid` , you may need to display error when input is dirty or touched:

the direct code:

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group" [ngClass]="form.get('email').invalid && (form.get('email').dirty || form.get('email').touched)"> // add has-error here.
  <label> Email address </label>
  <input type="email" class="form-control m-input" formControlName="email">
  <span class="m-form__help"> Email is required. </span> 
</div>
```

better way:

- using accessor like the guide do  https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation
- Using method to check it

for example:

```
 <div class="form-group m-form__group" [ngClass]="displayCssFor('email')"> // add has-error here.
      <label> Email address </label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control m-input" formControlName="email">
      <span class="m-form__help"> Email is required. </span> 
    </div>
```

and typescript:

```
displayCssFor(field: string|Array<string>) {
    return (this.form.get(field).invalid && (form.get(field).touched || form.get(field).dirty) ) ? 'has-error' : '';
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware of using ngClass. My goal is to streamline the ngClass code. It's to repetitive.I was thinking a directive that accepts the form control as an argument.

Comment: Accessor method is the definitive solution. You Rock! Thanks again!